# ¿Como puedo llevar estos callbacks a promises con async/await?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo varios callbacks en archivos diferentes y me gustaria llevarlos a promises con async/await, pero no tengo muy claro de como hacerlo.

Explico de forma resumida el flujo.

En el archivo user tengo tengo un llamado al metodo authUser(this,usuario,clave) donde le paso como parametros toda la clase actual, usuario y clave, para que este metodo pueda formar lo necesario para hacer una peticion http.

este metodo llama a su vez al metodo post y este ultimo resive la respuesta de la api o web service.

```js
//archivo user

this.userProvider.authUser( this, this.username, this.password )

//archivo userProvider

authUser (callback,username: string, password: string) {

    let lowerName = username.toLowerCase()
    let passwordMd5 = Md5.hashStr(password).toString()
    let loginObject = {
      idOperation: ID_OPERATION.LOGIN,
      className: CLASSNAME.USUARIO_TO,
      userName: lowerName,
      password: passwordMd5,
      logAccesoObject: {
        userName: lowerName,
        sessionId: '',
        canal: CHANEL.CPM,
        modulo: MODULE.LOGIN,
        funcion: MODULE.LOGIN,
        operacion: MODULE.LOGIN,
        RC: 0,
        IP: '',
        dttimesstamp:  this.utilsProvider.getDate(),
        lenguaje: 'ES'
      },
      token: ''
    }

    
    this.httpCpoProvider.post(loginObject, 
    (response: any) => {
      console.log('logout Response Success')
      callback.onLoginRetrieve(response)
    },
    (error: any) => {
      console.log('logout Response Error')
      console.log(error)
      callback.onError(-33)
    })

}

//archivo httpCpoProvider

post( requestObject: any, callback, errorCallback){
    
    if(true){
      
      this.converterHttpPost (requestObject).then(response => {
     
        let dataRes = JSON.parse(response.data)

        if(dataRes.rc == 0){
          callback(dataRes)
        }else{
          if(dataRes.rc !== 0 || dataRes.rc != -33){
            callback(dataRes)
          }else{
            errorCallback(-33)   
          }

        }

      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error) {
          errorCallback(error)
        } 
      });

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

La idea es devolver `Promise<T>` (en verdad, cualquier otro *thenable*, pero `Promise<T>` es realmente la manera más sencilla y extendida).

Primero refactorizamos el método `post`, para devolver una `Promise<T>`.

```
const post = (requestObject: any): Promise<any> =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.converterHttpPost(requestObject)
            .then(response => {
                let dataRes = JSON.parse(response.data);
                if (dataRes.rc == 0) {
                    resolve(dataRes);
                } else {
                    if (dataRes.rc !== 0 || dataRes.rc != -33) {
                        resolve(dataRes);
                    } else {
                        reject(-33);
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
```

El método `resolve` completa la `Promise<T>` y devuelve un valor `T`.
Así podemos llamar al método `post` de forma asíncrona, en el método `authUser`, que a su vez también devolverá una `Promise<T>`.

```
type AuthResponse = any;

const authUser = (username: string, password: string): Promise<AuthResponse> => 
    new Promise<AuthResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
        const loginObject = this.getLoginObject(username, password);
        this.httpCpoProvider.post(loginObject)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('logout Response Success');
                resolve(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('logout Response Error', error)
                reject(-33);
            });
    });
```

El *parsing* del `loginObject` lo he sacado en un método separado por el bien de la claridad.

Una vez refactorizado el método `authUser`, podemos llamarlo sin hacer uso de *callbacks*.

```
const onLoginRetrieve = (response: AuthResponse) => { }
const onError = (error: number) => { }

this.userProvider.authUser(this.username, this.password)
    .then((response: AuthResponse) => {
        this.onLoginRetrieve(response);
    })
    .catch((error: number) => {
        this.onError(error);
    });
```

Esta sería la forma en Javascript, usando los métodos `then` y `catch`. En Typescript, podríamos refactorizarlo para usar `async`/`await`.

```
const method = async () => {
    const username = '';
    const password = '';
    // ...

    try {
        const response = await this.userProvider.authUser(username, password);
        this.onLoginRetrieve(response);
    } catch (error) {
        this.onError(error);
    }
}
```

De la misma forma podrías refactorizar el método `authUser` para *awaitear* la respuesta del método `post`, en vez de usar `then`/`catch`.

También te aconsejo tipar los objectos, así como las funciones. Por ejemplo, tipar la respuesta del método `converterHttpPost`, el objeto `loginObject`, inclusive ese error `-33` podrías tiparlo de la forma `type ResponseError = -33;`.

Por último, dejo el método `getLoginObject` que usé más arriba, aunque es exactamente igual que lo que hacías tú en tu código.

```
const getLoginObject = (username: string, password: string) => {
    let lowerName = username.toLowerCase();
    let passwordMd5 = Md5.hashStr(password).toString();
    return {
        idOperation: ID_OPERATION.LOGIN,
        className: CLASSNAME.USUARIO_TO,
        userName: lowerName,
        password: passwordMd5,
        logAccesoObject: {
            userName: lowerName,
            sessionId: '',
            canal: CHANEL.CPM,
            modulo: MODULE.LOGIN,
            funcion: MODULE.LOGIN,
            operacion: MODULE.LOGIN,
            RC: 0,
            IP: '',
            dttimesstamp:  this.utilsProvider.getDate(),
            lenguaje: 'ES'
        },
        token: ''
    };
}
```

Espero que te sirva.